# nsis Advanced Uninstall Log - uninstaller needs to reside in a different dir

Tags: logging, header, nsis, uninstallation

Requirement 1:
It is required that our uninstaller remove only files in a specific folder installed by the installer (i.e. any files added after install must remain intact).

Requirement 2:
It is also required that the uninstaller reside in a specific location other than the above mentioned folder.

I found and have experimented with the "Advanced Uninstall Log NSIS Header" found here :
http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Advanced_Uninstall_Log_NSIS_Header

While the Advanced Uninstall Log NSIS Header looks very promising, (meets requirement 1 quite well), I am unable to determine if I can make it also work with Requirement 2.

Can the header be used to uninstall only installed files AND be invoked from a different dir other than the dir in which the .dat file is created?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you willing to modify AdvUninstLog.nsh? It can probably be done without any modifications but it will be a bit more work...

Comment: Hi Anders - yes I am willing to modify AdvUninstLog.nsh and have looked into it, but don't know where to start. Have any suggestions?   (If this is not the proper forum for such a discussion, please redirect me to the appropriate place.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AdvUninstLog.nsh you should comment out anything related to `UNINST_EXE`, especially the `WriteUninstaller` line. I was not sure if you wanted the .dat and the uninstaller in the same directory so I used separate directories just to be on the safe side.

```
...
!include AdvUninstLog.nsh
!insertmacro UNATTENDED_UNINSTALL
Page Directory 
Page InstFiles

Function .onInit

    !insertmacro UNINSTALL.LOG_PREPARE_INSTALL

FunctionEnd


Function .onInstSuccess

    !insertmacro UNINSTALL.LOG_UPDATE_INSTALL

FunctionEnd

Section "Main Application"

    SetOutPath "$InstDir\foo"
    WriteUninstaller "$InstDir\foo\uninst.exe"

    SetOutPath "$InstDir\data"
    !insertmacro UNINSTALL.LOG_OPEN_INSTALL
    File /r "${NSISDIR}\Plugins\*" ; "random" files
    !insertmacro UNINSTALL.LOG_CLOSE_INSTALL

    WriteRegStr ${INSTDIR_REG_ROOT} "${INSTDIR_REG_KEY}" "InstallDir" "$InstDir"
    WriteRegStr ${INSTDIR_REG_ROOT} "${INSTDIR_REG_KEY}" "DisplayName" "${APP_NAME}"
    WriteRegStr ${INSTDIR_REG_ROOT} "${INSTDIR_REG_KEY}" "UninstallString" '"$InstDir\foo\uninst.exe"'

    ; Because the UNINSTALL.LOG_UPDATE_INSTALL macro is responsible for writing the .dat
    ; it is important to set $InstDir to the directory you want it to be located in.
    ; This must be done as the last step in your last Section so that $InstDir has
    ; the correct path when .onInstSuccess is executed.
    SetOutPath "$InstDir\bar" ; Make sure the directory exists
    StrCpy $InstDir "$InstDir\bar"

SectionEnd

Section UnInstall

    ; In the uninstaller the initial value of $InstDir is the folder the uninstaller .exe is in.
    ; In this example I put it in a subfolder so we need to get the root of our install:
    GetFullPathname $InstDir "$InstDir\..\"

    ; This is important, it changes $InstDir to the folder where the .dat is located.
    Push $InstDir ; Save
    StrCpy $InstDir "$InstDir\bar" 
    !insertmacro UNINSTALL.LOG_BEGIN_UNINSTALL
    Pop $InstDir ; Restore

    !insertmacro UNINSTALL.LOG_UNINSTALL "$INSTDIR\data"
    !insertmacro UNINSTALL.LOG_END_UNINSTALL
    DeleteRegKey /ifempty ${INSTDIR_REG_ROOT} "${INSTDIR_REG_KEY}"

    ; Because the uninstaller and the .dat were located in their own (unlogged) folders
    ; we need to manually delete them:
    Delete "$INSTDIR\foo\uninst.exe"
    RMDir "$INSTDIR\foo"
    Delete "$INSTDIR\bar\${UNINSTALL_LOG}.dat"
    RMDir "$INSTDIR\bar"

    RMDir "$INSTDIR"

SectionEnd
```

Comment: Your code works great! No I just need to figure out how to shoe-horn the relevant parts into my app.